# CakePHP ""_joinData" is missing from the belongsToMany results" Error

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currently in the process of updating old projects from cakephp 3.1.3 to 3.7.4.

For one of the projects I got the error 
"_joinData" is missing from the belongsToMany results

I was unable to find any explanation to that specific error and since I am relatively new to PHP and CakePHP. and usually don't do much with databases I am currently a littlebit stuck despite lot's of information's about associations and CakePHP tables in general.

The error happens after an first() call on an model, like

```
$foundInstances = $instances->find()
            ->where([
                        'type_id' => $instanceTypeId,
                        'id' => $this->otherModel->id
                    ])
            ->contain(['Features'])
            ->enableHydration(false);
$this->instances->first()
```

In the model class the relationsa re simply set like this:

```
$this->belongsToMany('BackendFeatures', [
        'setForeignKey' => 'instance_id',
        'setTargetForeignKey' => 'backend_feature_id',
        'joinTable' => 'backend_features_instances'
    ]);
$this->belongsToMany('Features', [
        'setForeignKey' => 'instance_id',
        'setTargetForeignKey' => 'feature_id',
        'joinTable' => 'features_instances'
    ]);
```

Can someone maybe give me an hint what i have to be looking for?

Comment: Okay, nevermind, it was an caching issue.. I thought in debugging mode cake would delete the caching itself o.O

Comment: It will, but still only as configured (every x seconds).

Comment: Well, i was struggling with this for over an Hour, I'm quite sure that it should have been deleted by then.

Comment: Then you misconfigured your local (dev) cache. https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/fa2b3fbf6bc0c9411bce3ee1556e97a334a583ee/config/bootstrap.php#L90-L95